# Hash function for an integer sequence

Tags: hash

Say there is a list of permutations. Each permutation is a long list of integers. Let's consider a sample permutatation and call it samplePerm. My task is to find out if the list contains the samplePerm. I think that it will be a good idea to use a hash function technique. So that permutations are very large (more than 10000 items) the polinomial variant (like for strings) is useless. Does anybody know the best practice?

*UPDATE:*
THE ORDER OF INTEGERS IN A PERMUTATION IS A KEY CRITERION! All permutations consist of the same numbers

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: That is not. That is an optimization idea for my program...

Comment: Does the order of the permutations matter?

Comment: What do you think about converting a permutation into a string some way or work with groups of integers..?

Comment: @Andy, thank you for your question! See updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is dividing integers into groups and considering each group as a string via concatenating integers. After that it is possible to apply a hash function (see java String.hashCode() for an algorithm) to each group. Finally it is possible to add the result numbers. The last activity may provide collisions so it is a place where it is required a better idea :)